# How to test a REST API with Behat and Mink in Symfony 2

Tags: php, rest, symfony, behat, mink

I'm builing a REST API in Symfony and I'd like to test it with Behat (using Mink and the behat extension for symfony2). There's no problem for the GET methods, I just "mock" some database objects, use the "I am on " step definition and check the response.

But when it comes to test if the post of a certain element works I don't know how to send post params with Mink. I know it could be done with i.e. Guzzle but I think it would be much better doing it through Mink and the Symfony extension.

What I'm looking for is the way to define a step such as

```
When I POST to <url> the following data:
| field1 | field2 | field3 |
| value1 | value2 | value3 |
```

Is there any easy way to send this using Mink? Thanks!

Comment: @CarlosGranados yep, I already read that article. The problem is that makes a simple post request and I'd like to make an internal request the way mink does with symfony

Comment: [Api request response testing with behat v2 includes json, xml, html and cli](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/ajqn/api-request-response-testing-with-behat-v2-includes-json-xml-html-and-cli) and [Api request response testing with behat v1](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/xw1v/api-request-response-testing-with-behat-v1)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
$session->getDriver()->getClient()->request ('POST', $url, $postdata);
```

This is what mink uses for its `visit` method only using get instead of post

Comment: What is the format of the $postdata? Is it key=>value array?

Comment: The $postdata signature is in the symfony/browser-kit/Client.php.  Yes, $postdata is an associative array.

Comment: @KonstantinPereiaslov BrowserKit driver also supports POST. https://github.com/minkphp/MinkBrowserKitDriver/blob/master/src/BrowserKitDriver.php#L144